# Continuity of homotopy in proof of Hopf's Umlaufsatz

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, continuity

The standard proof of Hopf's *Umlaufsatz* proceeds something like
this: We have a unit speed $\mathcal{C}^1$ curve $\beta:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$.  Furthermore,
$\beta$ is a simple loop with period $L$.
We now define $T=\{(t_1,t_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0 \leq t_1 \leq t_2 \leq L \}$
and a function $f$ on $T$ as follows:

$$ f(t_1,t_2) =
  \begin{cases}
    \beta'(t_1) & t_1=t_2 \\
    -\beta'(0) & (t_1,t_2)=(0,L) \\
    \frac{\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1)}{\|\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1)\|} & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases} $$

It is [visually obvious](http://www.mathematik.com/Hopf/)
that $f$ is continuous, but I haven't found a strict proof of this anywhere.
Below is my attempt at a proof, but I think it's ugly and long-winded and it
also isn't complete.  My question is how to finish it.  I also suspect (or
rather hope) that there is a significantly shorter (or more elegant) proof
that is nevertheless complete and doesn't use hand-waving.

First of all, $f$ is continuous for all $(t_1,t_2)\in T$ with $t_1\neq t_2$
and $(t_1,t_2)\neq(0,L)$ because (as $\beta$ is simple) the denominator of
$(\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1))/(\|\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1)\|)$ doesn't
vanish and $\beta$ and the norm are continuous.

Now for the case $t_1=t_2$.  Fix $t_1\in[0,L]$.  We have
$$ \lim_{t_2\to t_1} \frac{\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1)}{t_2-t_1} = \beta'(t_1) $$
by definition.  This implies
$$ \lim_{\substack{t_2\to t_1\\t_2>t_1}} \frac{\|\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1)\|}{t_2-t_1} = \lim_{\substack{t_2\to t_1}} \left\|\frac{\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}\right\| = \|\beta'(t_1)\| = 1 $$
as $\beta$ is a unit speed curve.
Combining these two we get
$$ \lim_{\substack{t_2\to t_1\\t_2>t_1}} f(t_1,t_2) = \lim_{t_2\to t_1} \frac{\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1)}{t_2-t_1} \cdot 
\lim_{\substack{t_2\to t_1\\t_2>t_1}} \frac{t_2-t_1}{\|\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1)\|} = \beta'(t_1) $$

This means that for every $\varepsilon>0$ we can find a $\delta>0$ such that
for all $t_2$ with $|t_2-t_1|<\delta$ and $(t_1,t_2)\in T$ we have
$\|f(t_1,t_2)-\beta'(t_1)\|<\varepsilon$.

As $[0,L]$ is compact, we can even, for a given $\varepsilon>0$, find a $\delta_1>0$
such that for *all* $(t_1,t_2)\in T$ with $|t_2-t_1|<\delta_1$ the inequality
$\|f(t_1,t_2)-\beta'(t_1)\|<\varepsilon/2$ holds.

Also, as $\beta'$ is continuous and $[0,L]$ is compact, we can find a
$\delta_2>0$ such that for all $t_1^\ast,t_1\in[0,L]$ with $|t_1-t_1^\ast|<\delta_2$ we
have $\|\beta'(t_1) - \beta'(t_1^\ast)\|<\varepsilon/2$.

Now let $P=(t_1,t_2)\in T$ be arbitrary with
$\|P-(t_1^\ast,t_1^\ast)\|<\min\{\delta_1/2,\delta_2\}$.  That implies
$|t_1-t_1^\ast|<\delta_2$ and $|t_2-t_1|<\delta_1$.  By combining the
previous two inequalities we get
$\|f(P)-\beta'(t_1^\ast)\|<\varepsilon$.  We have thus proved that
$f$ is continuous in $(t_1^\ast,t_1^\ast)$.

The third case is the point $Q=(0,L)$.  As $\beta$ is a loop, we have:
$$ \lim_{t\to L} \frac{\beta(t)-\beta(0)}{L-t} = -\lim_{t\to L} \frac{\beta(L)-\beta(t)}{L-t} = -\beta'(L) = -\beta'(0) $$
And as a consequence we have:
$$ \lim_{\substack{t\to L\\t<L}} \frac{\|\beta(t)-\beta(0)\|}{L-t} = \lim_{\substack{t\to L}} \left\|\frac{\beta(t)-\beta(0)}{L-t}\right\| = \|-\beta'(0)\| = 1 $$
Combining these two we get, as above:
$$ \lim_{\substack{t\to L\\t<L}} f(0,t) =  -\beta'(0) $$

At this point I'm stuck.  I think that we need to show that $f$ is uniformly
continuous around $Q$ and that maybe this is the case because $\beta$ has
unit speed.  If we can prove that, we can approach $Q$ in a way similar to the
second case: starting from a point near enough we first move - by virtue of
uniform continuity - parallel to the $x$ axis until the first component is
zero.  Then we move vertically towards $Q$.

**EDIT:**

Using Ted Shifrin's advice, I've rewritten the second case of the proof.
However, it seems to me that this depends on the Taylor remainder $R$ being
continuous in *both* variables (see question mark below) which - if justified in
detail - is not much different from what I did above and still doesn't solve
the third case.  Or am I missing something?

As $\beta$ is differentiable, we can write, for each $t_1\in[0,L]$,
$$ \beta(t_2)=\beta(t_1)+(t_2-t_1)\cdot\beta'(t_1) +(t_2-t_1)\cdot R(t_1,t_2-t_1) $$
with $\lim_{t\to0}R(t_1,t)=\mathbf0$.

We thus have
$$ \lim_{(t_1,t_2)\to(t_1^\ast,t_1^\ast)} \frac{\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1)}{t_2-t_1} = \lim_{(t_1,t_2)\to(t_1^\ast,t_1^\ast)} (\beta'(t_1) + R(t_1,t_2-t_1)) \stackrel{\color{red}?}{=} \beta'(t_1^\ast) $$
and
$$ \lim_{\substack{(t_1,t_2)\to(t_1^\ast,t_1^\ast)\\t_2>t_1}} \frac{\|\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1)\|}{t_2-t_1} = \lim_{\substack{(t_1,t_2)\to(t_1^\ast,t_1^\ast)\\t_2>t_1}} \left\|\frac{\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}\right\| = \|\beta'(t_1^\ast)\|=1 $$
which eventually leads to 
$$ \lim_{\substack{(t_1,t_2)\to(t_1^\ast,t_1^\ast)\\t_2>t_1}} f(t_1,t_2) = \beta'(t_1^\ast)  $$
as above.

Comment: The proof I've usually suggested is to use a Taylor expansion of $\beta$ around $t=t_1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your help, but if I understand you correctly, this doesn't solve my problem.  I've added an alternative proof based on your suggestion to my question but I think I'm still stuck.

Comment: I admit I hadn't read your original post as carefully as I should have. For the main case you added based on my comment, you should use the Taylor expansion at $t=t_1^*$, fixed. I also don't know why you're saying in your original exposition that you have continuity at $P$; it should say at $(t_1^*,t_1^*)$? If you replace the interval $t_2\in (L-\delta,L]$ with the interval $t_2\in (-\delta,0]$ the previous diagonal argument should work just fine (if you pay attention to the sign).

Comment: @TedShifrin I've now added a proof as an answer which I think should work.  I also tried the Taylor expansion with $t=t_1^\ast$ fixed, but couldn't make it work.  (And, yes, "$P$" was a typo which I've fixed.)  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I'll put the whole proof here.  The "trick" is to enlarge the domain of $f$ so that both special cases are essentially the same except for the sign.

We have a unit speed $\mathcal{C}^1$ curve $\beta$.  Furthermore,
$\beta$ is a simple loop with period $L$.
We now define $T=\{(t_1,t_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0 \leq t_1 \leq L \text{ and } t_1 \leq t_2 \leq t_1+L \}$
and a function $f$ on $T$ as follows:
$$ f(t_1,t_2) =
  \begin{cases}
    \beta'(t_1) & t_2=t_1 \\
    -\beta'(t_1) & t_2=t_1+L \\
    \frac{\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1)}{\|\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1)\|} & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases} $$
We want to prove that $f$ is continuous on $T$.

First of all, $f$ is continuous for all $(t_1,t_2)\in T$ with
$t_2\notin\{t_1,t_1+L\}$ (the "otherwise" case in the definition) because (as
$\beta$ is simple and has period $L$) the denominator of
$(\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1))/(\|\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1)\|)$ doesn't
vanish and $\beta$ and the norm are continuous.

Now for the case $t_2=t_1$.  Fix $t_1\in[0,L]$.  We have
$$ \lim_{t_2\to t_1} \frac{\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1)}{t_2-t_1} = \beta'(t_1) $$
by definition.  This implies
$$ \lim_{\substack{t_2\to t_1\\t_2>t_1}} \frac{\|\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1)\|}{t_2-t_1} = \lim_{\substack{t_2\to t_1}} \left\|\frac{\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}\right\| = \|\beta'(t_1)\| = 1 $$
as $\beta$ is a unit speed curve.
Combining these two we get
$$ \lim_{\substack{t_2\to t_1\\t_2>t_1}} f(t_1,t_2) = \lim_{t_2\to t_1} \frac{\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1)}{t_2-t_1} \cdot 
\lim_{\substack{t_2\to t_1\\t_2>t_1}} \frac{t_2-t_1}{\|\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1)\|} = \beta'(t_1) $$

This means that for every $\varepsilon>0$ we can find a $\delta>0$ such that
for all $t_2$ with $|t_2-t_1|<\delta$ and $(t_1,t_2)\in T$ we have
$\|f(t_1,t_2)-\beta'(t_1)\|<\varepsilon$.

As $[0,L]$ is compact, we can even, for a given $\varepsilon>0$, find a $\delta_1>0$
such that for \textit{all} $(t_1,t_2)\in T$ with $|t_2-t_1|<\delta_1$ the inequality
$\|f(t_1,t_2)-\beta'(t_1)\|<\varepsilon/2$ holds.

Also, as $\beta'$ is continuous and $[0,L]$ is compact, we can find a
$\delta_2>0$ such that for all $t_1^\ast,t_1\in[0,L]$ with $|t_1-t_1^\ast|<\delta_2$ we
have $\|\beta'(t_1) - \beta'(t_1^\ast)\|<\varepsilon/2$.

Now let $P=(t_1,t_2)\in T$ be arbitrary with
$\|P-(t_1^\ast,t_1^\ast)\|<\min\{\delta_1/2,\delta_2\}$.  That implies
$|t_1-t_1^\ast|<\delta_2$ and $|t_2-t_1|<\delta_1$.  By combining the
previous two inequalities we get
$\|f(P)-\beta'(t_1^\ast)\|<\varepsilon$.  We have thus proved that
$f$ is continuous in $(t_1^\ast,t_1^\ast)$.

The third case is $t_2=t_1+L$.  This is almost identical to the second case.
He we have
$$ \lim_{t_2\to t_1+L} \frac{\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1+L)}{(t_1+L)-t_2} = -\beta'(t_1+L) = -\beta'(t_1) $$
because $\beta$ has period $L$.  And thus:
$$ \lim_{\substack{t_2\to t_1+L\\t_2<t_1+L}} \frac{\|\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1+L)\|}{(t_1+L)-t_2} = \lim_{\substack{t_2\to t_1+L}} \left\|\frac{\beta(t_2)-\beta(t_1+L)}{(t_1+L)-t_2}\right\| = 1 $$
When we combine these two, the only difference is the sign:
$$ \lim_{\substack{t_2\to t_1+L\\t_2<t_1+L}} f(t_1+L,t_2) = -\beta'(t_1) $$
We can now proceed like above to show that $f$ is continuous for all points of
the form $(t_1^\ast,t_1^\ast+L)$ and thus in particular at $(0,L)$.

Answer (score 1):

Continuity follows easily from converting it to an integral. You might want to look up the proof in John Lee's Introduction to Riemannian manifolds, 2nd edition, chapter 9.