# Hopf's proof of the Turning Tangents Theorem in "Differential Geometry in the Large"

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Rigorous proofs of the Hopf Umlaufsatz seem to always entail nightmarish details about covering maps and degree theory, or careful estimates as in the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3083408/continuity-of-homotopy-in-proof-of-hopfs-umlaufsatz). The strange thing is that Hopf's own argument in his notes "[Differential Geometry in the Large](http://users.auth.gr/users/3/2/050723/public_html/files/hopf_h_-_differential_geometry_in_the_large.pdf)" (page 42 of the Springer edition) seems confused and impossibly brief. He defines an entity he calls $V(s_1,s_2)$ and first says that it's "the argument of the vector pointing from $c(s_1)$ to $c(s_2)$". A few lines later he then says "the vector field $V(s_1,s_2)$" is "continuous" on it's domain and furthermore that "the variation of the argument of a continuous vector field around a closed path is zero", an assertion which he uses to quickly deduce the theorem with no estimates or degree theory. A few questions arise:

1. What did Hopf want V to be, really? A scalar field of angles, or a vector field?
2. Hopf's assertion, that a continuous vector field's argument doesn't vary around a closed loop seems false as stated; if this were true the Umlaufsatz itself would be false! He may have meant a vector field with no singularities inside the loop. But where can I find a proof of *this* assertion?
3. Is Hopf's reasoning sound, assuming we can make sense of 1 and 2 above? Can we really just say "the angle variation is path independent" and be done in a couple of lines?

Edit: Here's an attempt along the lines of Green's theorem as suggested by Ted Shifrin:

In Do Carmo (for instance) one can find the measure of the angle variation of a unit vector field $V = (a,b)$ along a curve $c(t)$ to be $\theta  = \int_c ab' - ba' dt$. Assuming $c(t)$ is parameterized by arclength, we write this integral explicitly with directional derivatives along $c$: $\theta = \int_c [(\nabla b \cdot c'(t)) a - (\nabla a \cdot c'(t)) b] dt = \int_c (a \nabla b - b \nabla a)\cdot c'(t) dt$.  The last integral is a line integral around $c(t)$ against the new vector field defined by $W=(P,Q)=(ab_x-ba_x, ab_y - ba_y)$. Applying greens theorem gives $\theta = 2\iint_R (b_y a_x - a_y b_x)dydx$. But this integrand vanishes since $a = \cos \theta(x,y)$ and $b = \sin \theta(x,y)$.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. Having multiple questions in the same post is discouraged and such posts may be closed, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6464).

Comment: Your link "as in the discussion here" does not work.  If you want to check out my differential geometry text (linked freely in my profile), I have Hopf's proof (pilfered mostly from S.S. Chern) on pp. 26-28. I assume his $V$ is my $\mathbf h(s,t)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I've fixed the link, wherein you actually participate in the discussion. If I had to reduce my questions to a single question, it comes down to "Can Hopf's short argument be salvaged?"

Comment: He means to assume that the vector field whose argument we’re discussing has no zeroes inside the simple closed curve. But I agree that the proof is far from rigorous. I still suggest that the proof in my text is more complete (although there is a generalized version of the key lemma left as an exercise). An alternative proof of the claim on the triangle will also follow from Stokes’s/Green’s Theorem, I believe.

Comment: @TedShifrin I've made an edit with an attempt using Green's Theorem. Perhaps this calculation used to be common knowledge? I confess I haven't seen it written down explicitly anywhere.

Comment: Green’s Theorem does not apply here, since the vector field $W$ is defined only on the curve, not inside. I was suggesting applying it to Hopf’s triangular region, where we have a continuous (but we’d need $C^1$) secant map defined on the entire region.

Comment: @TedShifrin I had in mind Hopf's triangle, but ultimately was hoping the reasoning would follow for any simply connected region where a nonsingular vector field was smoothly defined. . If we normalize the secant map to unit length, presumably we could write it in the form of my $V = (a,b)$ above, and the vector field $W$, being defined in terms of $V$, would be defined everywhere that $V$ was, including the interior of the triangle. Do we know a counterexample where the secant map fails to be smooth?

Comment: @TedShifrin Maybe the issue is that the variable $\theta$ depends on the path and isn't well defined across the entire region?

Comment: The secant map is as differentiable as the curve away from the diagonal. It is continuous there, by the argument I sketched there. It should be $C^1$ if we assume the curve is $C^2$, but that definitely requires some proof.